# DataGridView Filter Not Working?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dgovan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LenovoWarranty2\LenovoWarranty2\LenovoWarranty.accdb");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillData();
    }
    private void fillData()
    {

        //Init
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand cmd;

        //statement
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Warranty";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn1);
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

        //fill
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        //bind
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("SerialNumber LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("CompanyName LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);

        //BIND
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Whenever I input anything into the txtSearch textbox - nothing happens? Can anyone spot the issue?

I am trying to allow the user to filter through SerialNumber + CompanyName fields from my database using the txtbox_textchanged event so whenever a character is inputed, the rows will filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
```

Also I believe you are overriding the filter criteria instead of combining them. I think only the `CompanyName` filter will be used

Comment: bingo! It actually worked with both SerialNumber & CompanyName! :D

Comment: thought so, you'll need to combine the statements with an `OR` operator

Comment: tried that, gave me the red squiggly line with an error saying it cannot be applied to "string" and "string"

Comment: as in `string.Format("SerialNumber LIKE '%{0}%' OR CompanyName LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);`